# failed to open stream - no such file or directory - Lumen PHP

Tags: php, jwt, lumen

We capture mobile device information along with jwt token generated for it and store it in mysql table.

This is ensure the user is able to use the app on 1 or more devices allocated for the user as per the plan.

There is situation where user logs out from the devices or we force the user to logout of the device by invalidating the token. In that case below code is executed to invalidate the jwt token.

```
try {
       JWTAuth::manager()->invalidate(new \Tymon\JWTAuth\Token($token), $forceForever = false);
}
catch (JWTException $e) {
}
```

Below is tech stack

- PHP 7.2
- lumen
- Redis

Below image shown error occurs only with this api and not any other Api's. Not sure why its throwing an error related to cache.

[image]

Seems like whenever `sudo php artisan cache:clear` is executed on server it starts to work and again from next day it fails.

please let me know whats the reason for it

Comment: You should check what user the server runs under and avoid using sudo as it messes up with rights. Instead, follow official guidelines for Laravel/Lumen and set up directory permissions properly with chmod. See other topics like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434757/using-laravel-artisan-and-file-permissions) for a better understanding of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

my lumen was using local cache for some reason i forgot to change to redis which i was supposed to use. So now its fine.